# Filter RecyclerView with loadmore

Tags: java, android

I am using adapter filter and it works fine, but only on loaded data list, when trying to scroll recyclerview while searching things are massed up, code as below.

- my try for solution is mixed with current code.
- I tried filtering on server side, but its slow while searching.
- I need a solution that keeps things fast and simple.

==> activity search view:

```
srchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                if (adapterAll != null) {
                    adapterAll.getFilter().filter(s);
                    if (s != null)
                        saveSearchingText(s);
                    searching = true;
                }
            }else
                searching = false;

            return true;
        }
    });
```

==> 2 methods for starting and loadmore as below.

```
private void loadAllData(int index) {

    tag_string_req_loadAll = "req_loadAll";

    String currentUrl = Constants.url_get_all_data;

    strReq_loadAll = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            currentUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {

                    JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Model model = new Model("data");

                        if (!c.getString("status").equals("rejected")) {

                            model.setData(data);


                            list.add(model);
                        }
                    }

                    adapterAll.notifyDataSetChanged();

                
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                    

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

          
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("userId", userId);
            params.put("index", String.valueOf(index));


            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq_loadAll, tag_string_req_loadAll);
}
```

private void loadMore() {

```
    rv_all_data.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (notLoading) {

                int currentSize;

                if(searching){

                    currentSize = adapterAll.getItemCount() - 1;

                }else

                    currentSize = list.size() - 1;


                if (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == currentSize) {

                    rv_all_data.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Model model = new Model("progress");
                            model.setType("progress");
                            list.add(model);
                            adapterAll.notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
                            notLoading = false;

                            String tag_string_req_loadMore = "req_loadAMore";

                            String currentUrl = Constants.url_get_all_data;

                            StringRequest strReq_loadMore = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                    currentUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                                    adapterAll.notifyItemRemoved(list.size());

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                                        if (!error) {
                                            JSONArray jarray;
                                            String noMoreItems = jObj.getString("end");


                                            jarray = jObj.getJSONArray("items");

                                            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                                Model model = new Model("data");

                                                if (!c.getString("status").equals("rejected")) {

                                                    model.setData(data);

                                        
                                                        list.add(model);
                                                }
                                            }

                                    

                                            if (noMoreItems.equals("yes")) {
                                                notLoading = false;

                                            } else {


                                                //filtering new data
                                                if (adapterAll != null) {

                                                    adapterAll.getFilter().filter(getSearchingText());
                                                    
                                                }

                                                adapterAll.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                notLoading = true;

                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");

                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OOps, Something Went Wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OOps, Something Went Wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OOps, Something Went Wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }) {

                                @Override
                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    params.put("userId", userId);

                                    params.put("index", String.valueOf(list.size() - 1));

                                    return params;
                                }
                            };
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq_loadMore, tag_string_req_loadMore);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

==>adapter filter:

```
//filter in adapter

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String charSequence = constraint.toString();
            if (charSequence.isEmpty()) {
                list = searchList;
            } else {
                List<ModelAllCars> filteredResults = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Model model : searchList) {

                    if (model.getType().equals("data")) {

                        if (model.getBrand().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence)) {

                            filteredResults.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }

                list = filteredResults;

            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = list;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            list = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this `when trying to scroll recyclerview while searching things are massed up` .. what do you mean by "messed up", i.e. what is the exact issue you encounter when you search and scroll?

Comment: @Zain great, I mean that loadmore gets data and I can see that in logcat but all data are not showed on screen.

Comment: Does it work without the filter code being called at all?

Comment: You probably looking for the feature provided by the PagingLibrary from androidx that works for Room databases or custom datasources

Comment: @avalerio if I remove the searching boolean or put it false and remove the filter in loadmore it works and the filtering works only on the first loaded data and then  this condition is not true.
`if (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == list.size() - 1)`

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos could you explain more.

Comment: When a new filter criteria is active you should reload the items from the database or other datasource and start paging with the criteria, else your code will try to loadmore and the laoded data may not match your criteria and displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to load all data from the list when the user clicks the "see more" button, right ?

Knowing this, recyclerview must be recycling the list elements. You can just to change scroll Vertically to false.

```
new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I don't have a problem in loadmore, my problem is filtering data which is loaded by loadmore method.